# gcc 4.8 failed to check type conversion in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc4.8

I'm trying to update a c++ project's compiler from 4.8.4 to 7.5.0.
The codes can be well compiled with g++4.8.4. However, when I try to compile it with newer g++ 7.5.0. Lots of `Werror=conversion` errors are triggered.

Here is the demo code abstracted from my project:

```cpp
// main.cc
template <typename T>
int Hello(T obj) {
  float arg = 1.0;
  // return obj.func(arg);    // good, error detected for both g++ 4.8.4 and 7.5.0
  return obj.func(arg) * 2;   // failed to detect conversion error for 4.8.4, success for 7.5.0
}

class A {
  public:
    int func(int a) {
      return a;
    }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  Hello(a);
  return 0;
}
```

build:

```sh
g++ main.cc -Werror=conversion
```

As commented above, in a c++ template function, g++4.8 failed to detect the type conversion error when it's in a *expression*. But it will sucess if it is alone.
I'm very curious about this.
**My Question:**
Is this a bug of g++4.8? Why does *expression* matter?

Comment: Normally this is a warning. You explicitly made it an error. Either version should compile this, if it's a warning. The option is, by the virtue of its name, an optional, non-default compiler behavior, which gives the compiler a lot of leeway. You will find that successive, newer versions of gcc have progressively smaller tolerance for things that are not completely kosher. And that's a good thing. Try to compile your stuff with gcc 10 or 11, and see how far you get, with all warning now getting flagged as errors...

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Your answer made me relieved. Maybe I shouldn’t struggle with these historical issues. In fact, it's a good thing to improve our old project for the new compiler's 'less tolerance' checking. Thank you!.